# Confusing syntax error near unexpected token 'done'

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, for-loop, syntax-error

I am trying to learn shell scripting, so I created a simple script with a loop that does nothing:

```
#!/bin/bash
names=(test test2 test3 test4)
for name in ${names[@]}
do
        #do something
done
```

however, when I run this script I get the following errors:

> ./test.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token done'
>    ./test.sh: line 6: done'

What have I missed here? are shell scripts 'tab sensitive'?

Comment: Just see once http://stackoverflow.com/a/42478844/6545759 It may be helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, shell scripts are not tab sensitive (unless you do something really crazy, which you are not doing in this example).

You can't have an empty `while do done` block, (comments don't count)
Try substituting `echo $name` instead

```
#!/bin/bash
names=(test test2 test3 test4)
for name in ${names[@]}
do
       printf "%s " $name
done
printf "\n"
```

**output**

```
test test2 test3 test4
```

Comment: thanks that works =), is there a way I can get all output in one line?

Comment: note that `echo` is very handy to print line-by-line data as the original example showed. Learn about `printf` (search here on S.O. for examples) as it really powerful and flexible aid in formatting the printing of your data. Good luck.

Comment: A valid "no-op" command is [`:`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)

Comment: @glennjackman : yes, good point. As fenerlitk said 'I am trying to learn shell scripting', I figured it made sense that s/he would want to see the loop in action. Fenerlitk , note that the ':' no-op command could have been put in your loop, preceding you comment, i.e. `: # do something`, and that loop would have finished, but you wouldn't have seen anything happen. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 6):

`dash` and `bash` are a bit brain-dead in this case, they do not allow an empty loop so you need to add a no op command to make this run, e.g. `true` or `:`. My tests suggest the `:` is a bit faster, [although they should be the same](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34677/17666), not sure why:

```
time (i=100000; while ((i--)); do :; done)
```

n average takes `0.262` seconds, while:

```
time (i=100000; while ((i--)); do true; done)
```

takes `0.293` seconds. Interestingly:

```
time (i=100000; while ((i--)); do builtin true; done)
```

takes `0.356` seconds.

All measurements are an average of 30 runs.

Comment: I'd call not processing an empty loop a feature! ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter: Not processing is fine, doing a syntax error is not

Answer (score 4):

Bash has a built-in no-op, the colon (:), which is more lightweight
than spawning another process to run `true`.

```
#!/bin/bash
names=(test test2 test3 test4)
for name in "${names[@]}"
do
    :
done
```

EDIT: William correctly points out that `true` is also a shell built-in, so take this answer as just another option FYI, not a better solution than using true.

Comment: : is the correct no-op, but 'true' has been a builtin for a long time.  I imagine very few shells in use today would spawn a new process.

Comment: Bash `:` is like Python `pass` instruction

Comment: Also to note (5 years later), `:` is *required* by POSIX to be a built-in, while `true` is only optionally (but I bet almost always) a built-in.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the nothing with 'true' instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have something in your loop otherwise bash complains.

Answer (score 1):

This error is expected with some versions of bash where the script was edited on Windows and so the script actually looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash^M
names=(test test2 test3 test4)^M
for name in ${names[@]}^M
do^M
       printf "%s " $name^M
done^M
printf "\n"^M
```

where the ^M represents the carriage-return character (0x0D). This can easily be seen in vi by using the binary option as in:

```
vi -b script.sh
```

To remove those carriage-return characters simply use the vi command:

```
1,$s/^M//
```

(note that the ^M above is a single carriage-return character, to enter it in the editor use sequence Control-V Control-M)